# Net tasks called using BeginInvoke on the main form not executing

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface

I've used Visual Studio 2013 to build a C# application with a single form, and the application has two routines that update the screen.  The routines that update the screen need to run on the main thread, so my own threads (which don't interact with the screen) call the BeginInvoke method on the main form when updates are required.  However, something is happening somewhere in the application with the result that the two update routines stop executing.  I've put logging into the app to track the calls to BeginInvoke and the execution of the update routines, and I can see that when this problem occurs, the BeginInvoke calls are made, but then nothing.  When this happens, the whole application seems to freeze.  I can't think of what might be causing this.  How can I debug this?  Is there any way of looking at what's queued to run on the main thread?  When I run in debug and break into the application, all threads look normal, and the main thread doesn't appear to be doing anything, so why isn't it processing my pending update tasks?

Comment: Isn't the debugger help you? Just pause the debugger and see where main thread got struck .

Comment: Somebody may very well be able to give you an answer based on this description so I appreciate where you are coming from. But if it is at all possible, the inclusion of a short but complete program that demonstrates that isolates the problem would be great. It might also be helpful to some if you replace the `user-interface` tag with the specific UI technology that you are using (sounds like you are using `winforms`.)

Comment: BeginInvoke calls an asynchronous delegate, which will run on a background thread and you are not allowed to update the UI. Maybe you want to call Invoke (which is a method on the Windows base class Dispatcher). If you would provide some code it would be easier to help

Comment: @slfan - it is legitimate to update the UI with Form.BeginInvoke. If this method is called by a worker (non-UI) thread, the provided delegate effectively will be queued to execute on the UI thread. If called by the UI thread, the delegate will be queued to execute on the UI thread. In both cases _asynchronously_.

Comment: You can just press the `Pause` button in Visual Studio when the application gets stuck and you'll see *where* it is stuck. Most likely, the methods you're running asynchronously on the GUI thread are to blame, rather than `BeginInvoke` itself. Most notably, make sure two operations done using `BeginInvoke`/`Invoke` *don't* depend on each other. And don't forget to call `EndInvoke` ASAP in the invoked delegate.

Comment: @groverboy. You are right if the BeginInvoke call is on the control (I didn't know that this exists), which is what he probably does. It could be on a standard .NET event and then it's not handled by the Windows message loop. As I said the OP should provide more information.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments.  I *think* my problem is that something is accidentally calling this.BeginInvoke far too many times to update something, and I can't work out where it's being called from because it's a big application.  All ideas gratefully received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Control.BeginInvoke() adds the delegate to an internal thread-safe queue.  And posts a message to the UI thread to tell it to go have a look in that queue.  The message loop inside Application.Run() gets that message and goes about emptying the queue again, executing the delegates.

So if you don't see this happening then the most obvious reason is that the UI thread isn't inside the Application.Run() loop.  A standard mistake you could make is waiting for the thread to complete for example.  Very likely to cause deadlock.  Never wait, if you need to run code after the thread completes then consider BackgroundWorker's RunWorkerCompleted event or TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext().

The not-so-obvious failure mode of not seeing anything happening is that you are calling BeginInvoke() far too often.  If you do this more than ~1000 times per second, give or take, then you'll flood that internal queue with too many delegates.  The UI thread will actually be busy emptying that queue but can never catch up, always finding yet another delegate in the queue after executing one.  It goes catatonic when this happens, not taking care of its normal duties anymore.  Like responding to input and painting the windows.  No fix for this, other than limiting the rate at which you call BeginInvoke().  Do keep the target in mind, you only have to do it as often as the user's eyes can perceive.  Updating the UI at a rate more then 25 times per second is just wasted effort.

Comment: That's very useful :-).  This is a big application and I *think* something somewhere is indeed accidentally calling BeginInvoke to update something on the screen far too often.  Is there any way of looking in the threadsafe queue to see what routine is being scheduled?

Comment: Getting a breakpoint on this code is difficult, these are internal .NET methods and the message number is unpredictable.  You might get somewhere with the Reference Source but that's forever hit-and-miss.  Searching the codebase for "BeginInvoke" and reviewing the source control change log are the best strategies.

Answer (score 1):

This might be due to the two update routines attempting to update the UI at the same time. I've seen strange UI behaviour, e.g. partially updated controls, when many UI updates occur in a short space of time when triggered by multiple interleaved events. The two routines are *different* routines, yes?

A possible way to solve this is to use asynchronous delegate invocation on the UI thread. In the code below I've assumed that your UI is a WinForms Form, and I've named the two routines `UpdateA` and `UpdateB`.

```
private bool isUpdating;

public delegate void UpdateDelegate();

private void UpdateA()
{
    if (isUpdating)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new UpdateDelegate(UpdateA));
    }
    else
    {
        isUpdating = true;
        try
        {
            // ... do UI updates for A
        }
        finally
        {
            isUpdating = false;
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateB()
{
    if (isUpdating)
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new UpdateDelegate(UpdateB));
    }
    else
    {
        isUpdating = true;
        try
        {
            // ... do UI updates for B
        }
        finally
        {
            isUpdating = false;
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, I didn't use `lock` above to synchronise access to flag isUpdating, on the assumption that both UpdateA and UpdateB execute on the UI thread. They are invoked asynchronously by the worker threads via BeginInvoke.

Comment: Thanks.  I *think my problem is that something is accidentally calling this.BeginInvoke far too many times, and I can't work out where it's being called from.  Any ideas?

Comment: @Stochastically - Notes: (a) Hans Passant suggested searching your codebase for BeginInvoke; I agree. It may help to tracing (System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(...)) instead of logging because logging requires disk writes; use a tool like DebugView to show the time of each trace line. (b) The app doesn't freeze when you set a breakpoint, so it probably depends on timing, e.g. calls to BeginInvoke so frequent that they flood the delegate queue. If your worker threads really are trying to update the UI at this rate, and no other code is calling BeginInvoke, probably you can update the UI ...

Comment: ...  less frequently. If your workers can wait for every UI update to complete, use Invoke instead of BeginInvoke; this will dramatically reduce the delegates added to the queue. But the rate of UI updates may still be too high. You could devise a scheme to update the UI at most once per second. Or if updating a progress bar (0-100%) only call Invoke/BeginInvoke when the progress increases by at least 1 percentage point, i.e. calculate percentage progress on the worker thread not UI thread.

Comment: Thanks groverboy :-). It turned out that my delegate queue was indeed being flooded, but of course it turned out to be in a way and in an area of the code that I didn't expect, otherwise I wouldn't have had to ask this question!  Pity that it's not obvious how to review the delegate queue while debugging.  Anyway, thanks again for your thoughts :-).

Comment: @Stochastically - glad to hear you found the cause. I'm intrigued that it's an unexpected cause ... like a trap for young players. Maybe you could post an answer to describe it, and how you isolated it?  :-)

Comment: I thought that all stuff relating to my user interface was in the main form .cs file.  But I had forgotton that the form contains MDI child windows, and it was code in the child window that was causing the problem.  Just sloppy thinking, in a situation where there doesn't seem to be a way to look at what's happening because one can't see what's queued for the main thread.  Curious thing was, whenever I used Visual Studio to "break all", the main thread was never in the bit of code that was causing the problem.  Anyway, seems OK now :-).  Thanks!